# Parse file lines, using multiple variables in bash loop

Tags: bash, loops, grep

Given a file with 2 columns, a string and a filename, how can these be looped with a grep command? Would also like to direct the output to same name as SEQFILE in different folder. Believe the following is close, with correct quoting missing:

```
while IFS=" ", read SEQID SEQFILE
do
grep -A1 -m 1 ${SEQID} ${SEQFILE} > ./tmp/${SEQFILE}
done < missingSeq.txt
```

Comment: Is the file comma or space delimited? Your IFS above would make me think either/both.

Comment: one thing is your ifs .. the second is your redirection operator >

Comment: what exactly you want to do with grep command

Comment: Can you be sure that the second field is unique over the `missingSeq.txt` file? Because if it is not, later occurrences will overwrite earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is comma delimited, then `IFS=" ",` makes no sense, but if it's whitespace delimited, then the comma is getting in the way. This is likely to solve the problem you present above:

```
while IFS=' ' read id file; do
    grep -A1 -m1 "$id" "$file" > "./tmp/$file"
done < missingSeq.txt
```

Comment: You're right it is whitespace, and the extra comma was the error. The two column file is an error report from a job run in parallel, and it is needed to append each SEQID (and following line) for each filename. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=' '
while read seq_id seq_file; do
   grep -A1 -m1 "$seq_id" "$seq_file" >> ./tep/seq_file    # i assume "tep" was actually meant
done < missingSeq.txt
```

Comment: do the little do it clean

Comment: >> will append to the file..while > will overwrite